# Does the software-firewall of a virtual machines host also protect the guests?

Tags: firewall, virtualization, nat

Both: host & guest are running windows 10.
I use VMware for virtualization.

The guest VM connects to the internet via NAT.
I have a service running on the guest VM which I can access from the host.
But from another computer in the network, I cannot access this service.

So my guess would be that the host firewall is also blocking the port?

Comment: First off, if you want to access your guest OS from outside your own machine (host), you have to set your VM network adapter as bridged. Via NAT, your guest can access the Internet, but is otherwise invisible from outside the host. Regarding the firewall, and provided you enable a bridged connection in the VM, your host firewall will protect your guest, to some extent, because all incoming and outgoing traffic will go through the host anyway, but depending on the software you run on the guest, some traffic might not get stopped, that you would want to, for safety reasons.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation! Actually, I want to prevent reaching my guest from the outside. It is a service which is only relevant to myself. I was just trying to make sure that it is not possible.

Comment: With NAT enabled, you can reach the guest from outside the host only if you manually open ports in your router for the local IP address of the guest in the network. Then, you can reach the guest via the "192.168.x.xxx:zzzz" address, where zzzz is the port you opened for your guest in the router. Otherwise, your guest can access the Internet if you have set it up that way, but that's it.